# Sumproduct with multiple criteria on the same column not working

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, sum, sumproduct

I am writing a formula using SUMPRODUCT to show me the sum of a column with various criteria (i.e. multiple criteria in the same column) but I am getting 0 (zero) as a result, can anyone help me with this one? here is the formula:

```
=sumproduct(indirect($A10&"!E:E"),(indirect($A10&"!$F:$F")>=AA1)*(indirect($A10&"!$F:$F")<=AC1)*((indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand1")+(indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand2")+(indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand3")+(indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand4")))
```

The first part of the formula works well, but everytime I put this: `((indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand1")+(indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand2")+(indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand3")+(indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand4"))` then the problem appearing giving me 0 (zero) results

Comment: Share a sample workbook. You may use `--` Infront of brackets for or logics. Like `(--(indirect($A9&"!$D:$D")="Brand1")....`

Comment: it looks like A9 and A10 are not equal eg. you are trying to frankenstein two sheets into your formula. if thats true share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: oh, yes, I only noticed it now, lol, thanks for noticing, no wonder why it doesn't work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the filter way:

```
=INDEX(SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT(A10&"!E:E"), 
                  INDIRECT(A10&"!F:F")>=AA1, 
                  INDIRECT(A10&"!F:F")<=AC1, 
       REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT(A10&"!D:D"), "Brand1|Brand2|Brand3|Brand4"))*1))
```

Comment: thanks for this, I forgot about the regexmatch. Tried it with sumproduct and it works well, thanks for this.